# How to compare a String object attribute to a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, oop, string-comparison

I am writing a celebrity buzzfeed style quiz and I am having an issue trying to compare the ***ATTRIBUTE OF AN OBJECT*** (which is a string I checked using the GetType method) to a user inputed string. (yes I have used the type check method to test the type of the attribute, also I define the attributes as type string in the class). I know you can do this in python with == and in Java you can do this with the .compare method, but I am somewhat new to using objects in C# and so I'm not sure if there is a specific method to use.

[code i am trying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01IgM.png)

Celebrity class
[Celebrity Class 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wdtU.png)
[Celebrity Class 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwQtz.png)
I have already tried the String.Equals method as well as == operator to check and both give me the same error. In the picture I commented out the other conditional statements to make error checking easier. But basically this method takes a list of celebrity objects as well as a list of strings that were entered by a user, and in the end returns a Celebrity object (as per the quiz this will be the winner).

main.cs(58,17): error CS0119: Expression denotes a `method group', where a`variable', `value' or`type' was expected

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcWrQ.png)

Please let me know if this is impossible, or if this would work if the objects were not in a list.

Comment: Please include code as formatted text in the question, not as links to images.  This makes it much easier for people to help you and for the question to be useful to future readers.  Please also indicate the line which throws the error.

Comment: As it stands, it's impossible to relate the error message to the line which causes it

Comment: Please clarify your terminology.  Are you comparing class attributes, or object properties?

Comment: Please also include a definition of your Celebrity class -- otherwise it's hard to tell what's going on there.

Comment: You are converting all your strings ToLower, but compare it to "Ariana Grande". Of course this will always fail, it can never be equal.
Better use one of the overloads of String.Equals or String.COmpare and pass a StringComparer or a StringComparison, rather than converting all your strings ToLower().

Comment: @Holger No, in the second If statement i compare the object attribute (c.getName()) which is set as "Arianna Grande" to the string "Arianna Grande"

Comment: Right sorry. Most often this "method group" message appears, when you have not () behind a method. If you treat a Method like a Property.

Comment: @Holger thanks this seemed to be the issue I am surprised

Answer (score 4):

`c.getStarbucks` looks like it should be a method call i.e. `c.getStarbucks()`, and would cause the compilation error you are receiving.

Comment: I am comparing class attributes. c refers to each object in the Celebrity objects list and the getStarbucks and getColor return a string

Comment: @KatieTooher yes, but you have omitted the `()` after `getStarbucks`

Comment: @KatieTooher Do you have a different error now?

Comment: haha it works now thanks